# Turn cookie expire in minutes/hours that expires in days

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have java script, i used it for create cookie and i want to exipre it in 5hours but minimum expire time is one day..Can any one help me to turn this code to expire cookies in minutes/hours? I tried but I failed.Help me..

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

username='20';
setCookie("username",username,1);
```

1 is for one day,how to make it expiries in 5 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try. I hope it will work.

```
exdays = 5 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds);
exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + exdays);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct conversion would be setting the hours with `setHours` isntead of setting the day with `setDate`

```
exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + time_in_hours )
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a console open to view the two dates this outputs, but this would work (using `.setHours()`).

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exhours)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exhours == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    console.log(c_value);

    exdate.setHours(exdate.getHours() + exhours);

    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exhours == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    console.log(c_value);

    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

username = '20';
setCookie("username",username,5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MK5NH/

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exTime)
{
    var exdate=new Date();        
    exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + exTime);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exTime==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
setCookie("username",username,3600000);
```

This will set your cookie for 1 hour.